# Difference between row dates, in days, from the first entry to the current row entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAYS FROM date - first_value(date) over (ORDER BY DATE)) + 1 days
```

I had this code working fine but after switching the date column from `timestamp` to `date`, it's erring:

```
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT id, EXTRACT(DAYS FROM date - first_value(date) over (...
                   ^
    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried wrapping to_timestamp() around the date, but no luck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnAdX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subtract two `date`s from each other, so you do not need the `extract()` function at all:

```
SELECT date - first_value(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) + 1;
```

Note that the subtraction yields an integer number of days, just like the `extract()` function would. But unlike `extract()`, the above solution also works over month boundaries (like '9 July' - '27 June' = 12, where `extract()` would give -18 (unless you first turned the difference in dates into an `interval`)).

Comment: Thanks! But it's saying I need a timezone. "ERROR: cannot cast type integer to timestamp without time zone"

Comment: My bad. But it can actually be done much easier: see updated answer.